# How to convert json object to individual javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

Inside javascript

```
<?php
  echo 'var packages_disc = '.json_encode($packages).';';
?>
alert(JSON.stringify(packages_disc));
```

this is output of alert

```
[
  {"id":"3","package_name":"Standard","invoice_amount":"30000"},
  {"id":"4","package_name":"Premium","invoice_amount":"50000"},
  {"id":"5","package_name":"Luxury","invoice_amount":"120000"}
]
```

i want to get individual elements and assign to variable

Comment: You appear to have an array: which element of the array do you want to assign? (If you want all, then you'll not get much over treating the JSON as a literal in JS.

Comment: you mean you want the id,package_name etc etc in different arrays?

Comment: plz tell, what possible output you want?

Comment: That's an array of 3 objects.  Each object can be accessed using an index - `packages_disc[0]` and each property can be access from those objects - `packages_disc[0].id`

Comment: Create a function that loops over the array, and test for the `Object.package_name`.

Comment: if i want to alert only invoice amount

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array and find the object that fits your criteria...

```js
function getPackageByName(name) {
    return packages_disc.find(p => p.package_name == name);
}

var packages_disc = [
    {"id":"3","package_name":"Standard","invoice_amount":"30000"},
    {"id":"4","package_name":"Premium","invoice_amount":"50000"},
    {"id":"5","package_name":"Luxury","invoice_amount":"120000"}
];

var premiumPackage = getPackageByName("Premium");

alert(premiumPackage.invoice_amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `invoice_amount` based on `package_name`, it's like:

```js
var yourArray = [
  {"id":"3","package_name":"Standard","invoice_amount":"30000"},
  {"id":"4","package_name":"Premium","invoice_amount":"50000"},
  {"id":"5","package_name":"Luxury","invoice_amount":"120000"}
];
function getAmountByPackage(package_name){
  for(var i=0,o,l=yourArray.length; i<l; i++){
    o = yourArray[i];
    if(o.package_name === package_name){
      return o.invoice_amount;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(getAmountByPackage('Standard'));
console.log(getAmountByPackage('Premium'));
console.log(getAmountByPackage('Luxury'));
console.log(getAmountByPackage('Should return false'));
```